# How do I debug a exit-code failure for the specific service for my app?

Tags: python, uwsgi, systemd

I'm trying to run a Flask app through Apache. When I run

```
systemctl list-units --type=service
```

I see that the unit for this specific app, "SITENAME.service" has failed.

When I run

```
sudo systemctl status SITENAME.service 
I
```

get an error saying:

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/SITENAMEenv.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-01-01 21:26:25 UTC; 1min 1s ago 
Process: 787 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/SITENAME/SITENAMEenv/bin/uwsgi --ini SITENAMEenv.ini (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) 
Main PID: 787 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) Jan 01 21:26:25 ip-172-31-88-10 systemd[1]: 

SITENAME.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Jan 01 21:26:25 ip-172-31-88-10 systemd[1]: SITENAME.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Where can I get more information on this failure? I can't tell if this is a python issue in the actual application code, or something else.

The site stopped working a little while ago, but there were no major changes to the code. The service that is not working has the description "uWSGI instance to serve SITENAME"